# How to find all checkins by one user in p4

Tags: perforce

i am trying to get a list of all checkins made by a developer to the p4 repository since the beginning of time. I was unable to get this to work correctly from p4 command line. Can someone help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this should work: `p4 changes -s submitted -u user1220569`

For details refer to the [Documentation for p4 changes](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/changes.html#1048020)